# What is the use of passing additional data in CreateWindowEx

Tags: windows, winapi, state

In Windows API docs, it mentions that you can pass additional data like State Information to `CreateWindowEx()` function as its last parameter which can be accessed during `WM_CREATE/WM_NCCREATE` events. Then, you can store the state info inside the window itself using `SetWindowLongPtr()` function.

But what would be the point of doing this if we can directly set data using `SetWindowLongPtr()` immediately after Window initialization (inside wWinmain())?

Comment: Those two serve different purposes. Data passed in `CreateWindowEx` lasts until (after) `WM_CREATE`, data in `SetWindowLongPtr` lasts for the lifetime of the window.

Comment: @dxiv
I cannot seem to find anything about the lifetime of data passed through ```CreateWindowEx``` in Microsoft docs. Can you point it out please.
And still what would be the point of passing state info like that if we can directly use ```SetWindowPtr```

Comment: [CreateWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindoww) says it's a "*pointer to a value to be passed to the window ... by the ... WM_CREATE message ... sent ... before it returns.*". For example, it is safe to pass the address of a local variable, unlike for SetWindowPtr.

Comment: As to "*what would be the point*" that has been addressed in the posted answer. Basically, the data you pass into CreateWindow is made available to messages processed *before* the call returns i.e. before you have a chance to use SetWindowLongPtr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing user data through the `lpParam` parameter of `CreateWindow/Ex()` allows that data to be accessible to your window procedure *while* `CreateWindow/Ex()` is still running.  There are several messages sent to the window by `CreateWindow/Ex()` itself, including `WM_(NC)CREATE`.  When `WM_(NC)CREATE` is received, your data is accessible via the `CREATESTRUCT` pointed at by the `lParam`, and so you can then assign that data to the window via `SetWindowLongPtr()` (or `SetProp()`) for subsequent messages to access via `GetWindowLongPtr()` (or `GetProp()`).

If you wait until after `CreateWindow/Ex()` has exited before you then call `SetWindowLongPtr()`, those initial messages won't have a chance to access your data, unless you store it in a global or thread-local variable that the window procedure can access.

Whether or not that is acceptable to you depends on your particular situation.